# How do I enable a "VPN-bypassing" dummy localhost HTTP/SOCKS proxy with OpenVPN?

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

For as long as I've been using VPNs, I've had this problem: it's either "all VPN" or "all home connection". There is no obvious (to me) way to, for example, set up a certain Firefox profile to use my "straight home connection", or my cURL script controlled by PHP to "skip VPN" for a particular request.

This "binary" limitation has caused me countless headaches, ranging from having countless shopping orders declined (because they stupidly think it's "suspicious" if you don't use your home connection when ordering something) to problems with automating an "account balance check" bot for my bank's "Internet bank" (because, again, it uses the VPN and its proxies instead of my normal ISP connection).

The ideal and only sensible solution, as I figure it, would be if OpenVPN automatically set up a localhost-only HTTP or SOCKS5 proxy server on some port, allowing you to use this as a "VPN bypass". I say HTTP/SOCKS5 because these protocols are what's supported by individual applications (if any proxy is supported at all), including Firefox and my cURL scripts. If it would simply provide this, this would not be a problem. However, as far as I can tell, there isn't any such feature.

I've had so many serious problems resulting from this over the years, but I never found any acceptable/sane solution to this. They really make it impossible for me to do what ought to be the most obvious, basic feature one could possibly imagine. It's really maddening.

Please note that I'm talking about OpenVPN. I refuse to download/install any vendor-specific VPN "wrapper apps" which may support this, but I don't trust them for one second, and for good reason. They spy on you even more than when you use the more "neutral" and "industrial" OpenVPN client...

Also, I've heard things like "split a tunnel" or "set up this and that and blablabla" and it's always something awfully complex, often Linux-specific (I use Windows), and just "doesn't sit right with me". It seems too weird to me that they wouldn't provide some means to bypass the VPN connection, other than of course disconnecting from it, which would be a *massive* PITA to do constantly, not to mention it would break all kinds of things which require a constant connection.

Please don't suggest that I do things like those. If at all possible, this should be done in a very straight-forward and simple and obvious manner in OpenVPN, perhaps even a single configuration option that is for some reason disabled by default? I ***dream*** of something like:

```
bypass-vpn-proxy-server = 127.0.0.1:9876;HTTP
```

Then I would set up a Firefox profile called "Home connection", with the proxy set to use 127.0.0.1 on port 9876, and then any connection made in that Firefox profile would be using my actual home ISP connection and not go through the VPN as connected to via OpenVPN. Or SOCKS5, which Firefox also supports. (In fact, it supports both at the same time. Not sure what happens if you specify both...)

I really, really need to figure this out. It's ridiculous. You'd think this would be the first thing they'd think of when designing some kind of VPN client (OpenVPN)... but apparently not? I can't find anything as usual, but that says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH tunnel to your distant vm. To initiate a Port-Forwarding throuch such a tunne use something like:

```
~$: ssh -D 6666 -f -C -q -N user@<TARGET-HOST>
```

When the session is up, you can use `localhost:6666` to connect to your service.